# How does the Amazon app store know which device has installed the application?

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

I am little new to making apps for the Amazon app store and its In-App purchasing.

My issue is is this:

I have my application that has Amazon In-App purchasing. Now everything works fine, but I want to know how Amazon can tell which device has installed the application. Do they take the device ID, or they know it through Amazon ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge it would be amazon Id so that the user doesn't need to purchase the app multiple times. Also if it was done per device id, like the mac code, only one person could ever use that device with the amazon store.

Comment: So if it is Amazon ID, then a single ID can be used on multiple devices and all inapp packs can be unlocked just by paying once???

Comment: I believe it will unlock it for all. Once the transaction is made I dont think you will be able to do it twice. It should be then "attached" to the account.

Comment: I got it now, there three types of in app transaction "CONSUMABLE, ENTITLED, SUBSCRIPTION " so, if ur in-app pack is Consumable then you can buy it again and again but if it is ENTITLED and user has bought it then he cant buy it again but if user uninstalls and then reinstalls the app and then developer has to take care of transaction IDs properly. for further info on entitle in app read this:- https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/in-app-purchasing/documentation/entitlement.html